# Watermark and selected item padding

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Im creating a dropdown for post type using xamarin forms and syncfusion combobox. How to increase the left padding for the watermark(placeholder) to make it aligned with the placeholder position in picker or editor?

[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHsrL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

**Unfortunately**, from **[Customizing ComboBox in Xamarin ComboBox (SfComboBox)](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/combobox/customizing-combobox)** , there is no more way to change the position of `Watermark`.

The only idea I found that is add some `space` before word to make it work.

For example: `Watermark="    Enter 'A' to filter suggestions"`

The effect:

[image]